# Can a iPhone voice Recorder App always run in Background recording the Sounds and Play them?

Tags: iphone, audio-recording, multitasking

Can a App record the Voice in the surroundings even when it runs in the background and play the recorded audio? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multitasking doesn't allow audio recording to be in the background, so no.

Comment: Thanks Sevenotes. Is it possible to record and playback an audio simultaneously without any delay when the App is in the foreground.

Comment: Probably, yeah, but you'd likely end up picking up the audio you're playing with the mic. It'd be tough to filter it out.

Comment: Apple appears to have been accepting apps for iOS4 which continue to record audio when put in the background, so this may be an existence proof. The app has to declare itself as background audio capable, pre-allocate all audio resources and start the audio recording before the app gets backgrounded, and also expect to get killed if its memory or audio resources are required by the foreground app. So any use of system resources should be the absolute minimum.